# Docker Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

estoy empezando `Docker` pasando una `App laravel` pero puede conectarse a `mysql`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email`
```

**MySQL** funciona correctamente, de hecho puedo conectarme desde mi equipo, incluso ejecuté las migraciones, pero si despliego `laravel` desde `docker` este no tiene acceso, no puede conectarse a `MySQL`

```
version: '3'
services:
#laravel-docker es una imagen basada en php:7.4-apache
    laravel:
        image: laravel-docker
        container_name: php-laravel
        ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        networks: 
            - lan
        volumes: 
            - .:/var/www/html
        links:  
            - mysql

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: db_mysql
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 3306:3306
        volumes: 
            - volume:/var/lib/db_mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456'
        networks: 
            - lan
volumes:
    volume:
        driver: local
networks:
    lan: 
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Esa es toda la consulta que estás haciendo ?? Un select con where que no termina ??. Deberías mostrar la parte en donde estás haciendo al consulta para verla, y por que la estás generando mal.

Comment: @Excorpion si fuera por la consulta, ni siquiera funcionaria con `XAMPP`

Comment: Pero no funciona...

Comment: Como tienes configurado el `.env` de Laravel?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ las credenciales son las mismas con las que ejecuté en desarrollo, `localhost:3306, root, 123456`, `mysql ` ya está en docker, y cualquier sistema del `homestead` accede normal, pero no los levantados desde `docker`,